# Recovery of data behind applets

Tags: java, browser, applet

I'm trying to use an applet to recovery some old data on a 3rd party site that i wished to keep. I see that nowadays all browser that i know force java plugin to be unavailable, is there some technical workaround to allow current and future applet execution for the sake of data migration? i looked into Lobo browser and JWebPane but to no avail

Comment: i reworded question because i cant delete, if this is of no use could i ask to  delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about modern browser compatibility. You should still be able to use and older version of a compatible browser - I'd just be extra carefull as security fixes would obviously be absent.

This post might old some good infos on the subject: https://superuser.com/questions/999778/when-firefox-drops-java-applet-support-how-will-i-run-old-java-applets

However, keep in mind that the very existence of the applet plugin will cease with Java 9. I'd hurry to find a more futur-proof solution.

Comment: thanks, netscape did it